# How to transpose the contents of lines and columns in a file in Vim?

Tags: python, vim, text-files, text-parsing

I know I can use Awk, but I am on a Windows box, and I am making a function for others that may not have Awk. I also know I can write a C program, but I would love not to have something that requires compilation and maintenance for a little Vim utility I am making.

The original file might be:

```
THE DAY WAS LONG 
THE WAY WAS FAST
```

and  after the transposition, it should become:

```
TT
HH
EE

DW
AA
YY

WW
AA
SS

LF
OA
NS
GT
```

#### Update

- Golf rules apply to selecting correct answer.
- Python fans should check out [Charles Duffy’s answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/704139/254635).

Comment: Lowest number of characters... lowest score wins kind of thing.

Comment: It would have been even better if the solution transposed only the selected text... But, okay, the current solution is good enough for me. :)

Comment: The script in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320629/254635) seems to be the shortest Vim-only solution in the “golf” sense—that you have declared as the deciding factor for selecting between correct answers—among those posted so far, is it not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a command in Vim language. So you don't have to compile Vim with +python support.

```
function! s:transpose()
    let maxcol = 0
    let lines = getline(1, line('$'))

    for line in lines
        let len = len(line)
        if len > maxcol 
            let maxcol = len
        endif
    endfor

    let newlines = []
    for col in range(0, maxcol - 1)
        let newline = ''
        for line in lines
            let line_with_extra_spaces = printf('%-'.maxcol.'s', line)
            let newline .= line_with_extra_spaces[col]
        endfor
        call add(newlines, newline)
    endfor

    1,$"_d
    call setline(1, newlines)
endfunction

command! TransposeBuffer call s:transpose()
```

Put this in newly created .vim file inside vim/plugin dir or put this to your [._]vimrc.
Execute `:TransposeBuffer` to transpose current buffer

Comment: Pure vim gets you the nod.  Thank you so much!

Comment: An unnecessarily wordy solution, in my opinion.  By the way, technically speaking your solution does not work, since `1,$"_d` does not do what you probably want it to do.  I would write that line as `sil %d_`.

Comment: @ib why you say it doesn't? It works for me and it delete the whole file into anonymous register, does it not?

Comment: No, it does not: Open a nonempty buffer and run the Ex command you propose: `:1,$"_d`—nothing will be deleted.  You are trying to use the Ex command `:delete` the same way as the Normal mode command `d`.  However, both syntax and semantics of those commands are different!  The `:delete` command accepts an optional range before the command name, and an optional register name *after* (without `"`).  What you have written is the range `1,$` followed by a the *commented* text `_d` (see `:quote`).  Thus, the only effect your command has is moving the cursor to the last line of the current buffer.

Answer (score 10):

Vim support for a number of scripting languages built in -- see [the Python interface](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/if_pyth.html) as an example.

Just modify `vim.current.buffer` appropriately and you're set.

To be a little more specific:

```
function! Rotate()
python <<EOF
import vim, itertools
max_len = max((len(n) for n in vim.current.buffer))

vim.current.buffer[:] = [
    ''.join(n) for n in itertools.izip(
        *( n + ' ' * (max_len - len(n))
           for n in vim.current.buffer))]
EOF
endfunction
```

Comment: ++ oooh - was unaware that vim supported more than vimscript! Also perl, tcl, and ruby -- awesome!

Comment: It supports those scripts but not by default. You have to turn them on during build.

Comment: Right. Just about every distribution has a vim-full or vim-enhanced version, and I tested what I posted here against the Windows gvim

Comment: Crazy Kudos I am going to wait to see if any golf answer like four key strokes and your done win out.  I wonder what assumptions I should be allowed to make about the vim bulid itself to still be considered portable.

Comment: You still have to have python2X.dll somewhere on your computer for this to work. Python itself is not embedded in Vim.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Just to simplify your code, you can use `max(map(len, vim.current.buffer))` instead of `max((len(n) for n in vim.current.buffer))`, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

If scripts don't do it for you, you could record the actions to a register (the carriage returns are added for readability):

```
qa
1G0
xGo<Esc>p
1G0j
xGp
q
```

This will give you a macro that you could run against the example above, or any 2-line strings of the same length. You only need to know the length of the string so you can iterate the operation the correct number of time

```
16@a
```

A fairly basic solution, but it works.

Comment: The input domain could be more than two lines with the same length.

Answer (score 1):

The following function performs the required editing operations to
“transpose“ the contents of the current buffer, regardless of
the number of lines in it.

```
fu!T()
let[m,n,@s]=[0,line('$'),"lDG:pu\r``j@s"]
g/^/let m=max([m,col('$')])
exe'%norm!'.m."A \e".m.'|D'
sil1norm!@s
exe'%norm!'.n.'gJ'
endf
```

For the sake of “golfing”, here is its one-line version:

```
let[m,n,@s]=[0,line('$'),"lDG:pu\r``j@s"]|exe'g/^/let m=max([m,col("$")])'|exe'%norm!'.m."A \e".m.'|D'|exe'sil1norm!@s'|exe'%norm!'.n.'gJ'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Charles Duffy's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704130/can-i-transpose-a-file-in-vim#704139) could be shortened/improved using `izip_longest` instead of `izip`:

```
function! Rotate()
    :py import vim, itertools
    :py vim.current.buffer[:] = [''.join(c) for c in itertools.izip_longest(*vim.current.buffer, fillvalue=" ")]
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a vim plugin to do it. You can find it [here](https://github.com/salsifis/vim-transpose). Run `:Transpose` to transpose the whole file.