# How to print columns containing value

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Let's say I have a data file containing the following:

```
 1     2     3     4     5
67    88    12    32    22
 9    99    34    59    86
17     0    78     0    77
11     0     0     0    43
```

I would like to have a code that searches through each column for the number 0.  If the number 0 is found, the code will print out that entire column in a separate file.

With this data, the outputted file would look like so:

```
 2     3     4
88    12    32
99    34    59
 0    78     0
 0     0     0
```

It'd be great if the code didn't require me knowing the exact number of columns and/or row.

Comment: You do the search row wise and keep the entire row value.Explain what would you want?

Comment: I only want to keep those columns containing a value of zero.  For all columns not containing zero, I don't want them printed.  Searching by rows is fine, but I do not want to keep the entire row if it contains a zero value.  Basically, I'd like to have the rows searched for a value of zero.  If a zero value is found, the column containing the zero value is printed.  This is then done in succession for each column.  Does this help?

Comment: Your input file design is suboptimal for this sort of task.  Transposing to a row-oriented matrix instead of a column-oriented one would be a big improvement for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want.  It does not requiring knowing anything about how many rows or columns are present.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i==o)a[i]=1;next} {tab="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if (a[i]){printf "%s%s",tab,$i; tab="\t"};print ""}' file file
2       3       4
88      12      32
99      34      59
0       78      0
0       0       0
```

#### How it works

Because the file name is specified twice on the command line, the `awk` script will read the file twice, the first time to look for zeros, the second time to print.

- `FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i==o)a[i]=1;next}`

  One the first run through the file, `a[i]` is set to one for any column `i` that has a zero in it.

  This code only applies to the first run through because of the condition `FNR==NR`.  `NR` is the total number of records (lines) that we have read so far.  `FNR` is the number of records (lines) that we have read so far from the current file.  Thus, when `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first file.  The `next` at the end of the commands tells `awk` to skip the remaining commands and start over on the next line.
- `tab="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if (a[i]){printf "%s%s",tab,$i; tab="\t"};print ""`

  When we are reading through the file for the second time, we print out each column `i` for which `a[i]` is non-zero.  I chose tab-separated output but, by simply adjusting the `printf` statement, any format could be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '#n
# init and load line in buffer (1st line copied, other added)
s/.*/>& /;1!H;1h

# at end of file, load buffer in working area
$ {x
:cycle
# keep column if zero inside
   />[[:blank:]]*0[[:blank:]]/ s/>\(\([[:blank:]]*[0-9]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]][[:graph:][:blank:]]*\)/\2>\1/g
# remove treated column
   s/>[[:blank:]]*[0-9]\{1,\}\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:graph:][:blank:]]*\)/>\1/g
# is there another colum to treat ?
   />[[:blank:]]*[0-9][[:graph:][:blank:]]/ b cycle

# print result after cleanup
   s/>//gp
   }' YourFile
```

- Self commented sed
- posix versioj so `--posix` on GNU sed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting way of doing it with GNU awk:

*parse.awk*

```
# Record number of columns (assuming all columns have the same number of fields)
NR == 1 { n = NF } 

# First parse: Remember which columns contain `pat`
FNR == NR { 
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
    if($i == pat) {
      h[i] = i
      last = i>last ? i : last
    }
  next
} 

# Before second parse: switch to reading one field at a time
ENDFILE { 
  RS="[ \t\n]+"
} 

# Second parse: print field if current-record-number modulo 
#               number-of-columns is in the `h` hash
{ m = FNR % n }

m in h {
  ORS = (m == last) ? "\n" : OFS  # print new-line after last column
  print $1
}
```

Run it like this for example:

```
awk -f parse.awk pat=0 infile infile
```

Output:

```
2 3 4
88 12 32
99 34 59
0 78 0
0 0 0
```

Or with `OFS='\t'`:

```
awk -f parse.awk pat=0 OFS='\t' infile infile
```

Output:

```
2   3   4
88  12  32
99  34  59
0   78  0
0   0   0
```