# Creating new line for each n-column value, while maintaining Col. 1 value

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, row, col

I have the following type of data that is separated by tabs (n-columns):

```
-2  abandonar   abandono    abandonas   abandona    abandonamos abandonáis  abandonan   
-4  abandonado  abandonada  abandonados abandonadas 
-2  abandona    abandonos                                       
-3  secuestrado secuestrada secuestrados    secuestradas    secuestraría    secuestrarías   secuestraríamos secuestraríais  secuestrarían
```

I need to keep the values in Column 1, but I need each string in the following columns to be moved to their own line. The desired result would be this:

```
-2  abandonar
-2  abandono
-2  abandonas
-2  abandona
-2  abandonamos
-2  abandonáis
-2  abandonan   
-4  abandonado
-4  abandonada
-4  abandonados
-4  abandonadas 
-2  abandona    
-2  abandonos                                       
-3  secuestrado 
-3  secuestrada 
-3  secuestrados    
-3  secuestradas    
-3  secuestraría    
-3  secuestrarías   
-3  secuestraríamos
-3  secuestraríais
-3  secuestrarían
```

Is there a function in `awk` that would permit this type of action?
Simple writing out what I need to print on each line à la:

```
$awk '{print $1, $2, etc}'
```

would be very cumbersome, especially because there are 
Code:
n-columns

So far, I have tried out some `awk` solutions that help to solve problems regarding transposing the data. I found this solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534744/how-to-transfer-the-data-of-columns-to-rows-with-awk):

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) printf $i " " }'
```

and

```
awk '{
       for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) { a[NR, f] = $f } 
     }
     NF > nf { nf = NF }
     END {
       for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) {
           for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {
               printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS)
           }
       }
    }' input
```

However, they do not exactly solve the problem, as you can probably see, because I want each column to also be attached to the original value of its row in Column 1 and these solutions just transpose the data.
Any ideas of how I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then

```
awk '{ for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) print $1, $i }' filename
```

should work.

Comment: To be fair, as both answers were the same, so I just selected the first one as the correct answer.

Comment: @owwoow14 Select this one they beat me by a minute :)

Comment: @JID oops! You are right! Sorry :D Thanks for the help though, the solution (both of them) worked great!

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but this should work

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1,$i}' file
```