# How to read a block of rows into a single record with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parsing, split, text-processing

How would columns of data for a [block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75281663/4531180):

```
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ cat multiple_lines.data 
a 4
b 5
d 6
e 7
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ datamash transpose < multiple_lines.data > transposed.data
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ cat transposed.data 
a 4 b 5 d 6 e 7
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$ datamash transpose < transposed.data 
a 4
b 5
d 6
e 7
nicholas@mordor:~/powershell$
```

be fed into a `CSV` type file so that column `a` has the value `4`, etc?  Here `c` has been omitted, but it can be assumed to be present.  Or, at least that missing columns can be added.

No doubt `awk` would be fantastic at grabbing the above numbers, but looking to use `PowerShell` here.  Output to `json` or `xml` would be just as good as `CSV`, most any sort of output like [data interchange format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format) would be fine.

*Assuming an array of such blocks.*

Comment: Isn't that already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221265/1701026)?

Comment: I was more thinking of iterating a collection of such matrices @iRon

Comment: Again, isn't that what the referred answer does? Please try to build an PowerShell [mcve] that shows how you create your source collection and how the destination collection should be created. Displaying the output in the cli simply doesn't reveal enough information to help which where you looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Use Import-Csv instead of ConvertFrom-Csv when reading from a file.  Powershell will recognize automaically the space deliminater instead of the comma.

```
$txt = @"
a 4
b 5
d 6
e 7
"@
$table = $txt | ConvertFrom-Csv
$table
```

Comment: No, [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) recognizes only `,` as the field separator (delimiter) by default; you can override it with `-Delimiter`. That alone wouldn't be enough here, however, given that a _header row_ is missing. You can easily verify that your code doesn't do what you think it does with `$table | Format-List`