# How can I use awk to sort columns by the last value of a column?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have a file like this (with hundreds of lines and columns)

```
1  2 3
4  5 6
7 88 9
```

and I would like to re-order columns basing on the last line values (or a specific line values)

```
1 3 2
4 6 5
7 9 88
```

How can I use awk (or other) to accomplish this task?
Thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT**: I would like to thank everybody and to apologize if I wasn't enough clear.
What I would like to do is:

- take a line (for example the last one);
- reorder the columns of the matrix using the sorted values of the chosen line to derermine the order.

So, the last line is `7 88 9`, which sorted is `7 9 88`, then the three columns have to be reordered in a way such that, in this case, the last two columns are swapped.

---

A four-column more generic example, based on the last line again:

Input:

```
1    2 3  4
4    5 6  7
7 88.0 9 -3
```

Output:

```
 4 1 3 2
 7 4 6 5
-3 7 9 88.0
```

Comment: do you mean sort the last line and all line before it do same col swaps ?

Comment: Why do the first two rows get swapped, they are no longer in sorted order in either direction!?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use a specific line (in this case the last one) to re-order all the columns basing on the values of that line

Comment: So what does the value 7, 9 or 88 have to with the orders of line 1 or 2? The only transformation I can infer is you switch the last two values in every row which has nothing to with the values in the last row.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this question is about. Anyone figured it out?

Comment: @EdMorton I believe he wants to switch the order of columns such that the last row is ordered ascending.

Comment: @EdMorton my understanding is, he wants to sort the fields in last line, during sorting, the fields would be swapped. (so called re-ordered), after the sorting of the last line, he wants all lines above to do the same (re-ordering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick, dirty and improvable solution: (edited because OP clarified that numbers are floating point).

```
$ cat test.dat
1 2 3
4 5 6
.07 .88 -.09
$ awk "{print $(printf '$%d%.0s\n' \
                  $(i=0; for x in $(tail -n1 test.dat); do
                           echo $((++i)) $x
                         done |
                  sort -k2g) | paste -sd,)}" test.dat
3 1 2
6 4 5
-.09 .07 .88
```

To see what's going on there (or at least part of it):

```
$ echo "{print $(printf '$%d%.0s\n' \
                      $(i=0; for x in $(tail -n1 test.dat); do
                               echo $((++i)) $x
                             done |
                      sort -k2g) | paste -sd,)}" test.dat
{print $3,$1,$2} test.dat
```

To make it work for an arbitrary line, replace `tail -n1` with `tail -n+$L|head -n1`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Perl is really just an "improved" shell, with improved warts.

Comment: Your code works for the example, but strangely it does not work with my large matrix (100 columns and 27000 lines). It can be due to the format? All numbers are floats like ` 0.018344 -0.001763 0` etc.

Comment: @leonardvertighel: you didn't mention that the numbers are floating point. `sort -n` doesn't work with floating point numbers. Try using `sort -k2g` instead of `sort -k2n`

Comment: @rici unfortunately sort -k2g does not produce changes

Comment: @leonardvertighel: It works for me. Maybe you need to post a more realistic excerpt of your data. (And also the output of `sort --version`)

Comment: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`!!!! Stupid locale with its comma-separated decimals. Thanks all for your patience

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be elegantly solved using GNU awk's array sorting feature. GNU awk allows you to control array traversal using `PROCINFO`. So two passes of the file are required, the first pass to split the last record into an array and the second pass to loop through the indices of the array in value order and output fields based on indices. The code below probably explains it better than I do.

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"};
    NR == FNR {for (x in arr) delete arr[x]; split($0, arr)};
    NR != FNR{sep=""; for (x in arr) {printf sep""$x; sep=" "} print ""}' file.txt file.txt
4 1 3 2
7 4 6 5
-3 7 9 88.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. Is the last record `$0`? So can I put any column there?

Comment: @leonardvertighel, what specifically are you attempting to do?

Comment: reordering column of a matrix using a custom line (in this case the last one, but it can be any line or a median of some lines) as reference.

Comment: @leonardvertighel, to use say, line 30, from the file for reordering you would change `NR == FNR` in the script above to `NR == FNR && NR == 30`

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

Create a file called `transpose.awk` like this:

```
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str OFS a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}
```

Now here is the script that should do work for you:

```
awk -f transpose.awk file | sort -n -k $(awk 'NR==1{print NF}' file) | awk -f transpose.awk
1 3 2
4 6 5
7 9 88
```

I am using `transpose.awk` twice here. Once to transpose rows to columns then I am doing numeric sorting by last column and then again I am transposing rows to columns. It may not be most efficient solution but it is something that works as per the OP's requirements.

*transposing awk script courtesy of: @ghostdog74 from [An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash)*

Comment: I'm not sure just switching the last two values is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: I have a file like this **(with hundreds of lines and columns)**

Comment: @Kent: I didn't really understand your comment. (Though I may have misunderstood OP's requirement also :P)

Comment: @Kent: Honestly I couldn't figure out that from Original question. If you note timestamps OP has stated about sorting after my answer was posted.