# GnuPlot: Draw line per CSV line

Tags: csv, plot, gnuplot, dynamic-columns

I just started to work with Gnu Plot and i created a few simple plots. But now i have a new problem.

The input is a csv-file like this:

```
name;n0;n1;n2
Benj;1;3;2
Silv;6;1;2
Steffi;3;2;2
```

The count of the columns and the count of the rows is dynamic. So this is also a valid input file:

```
name;n0;n1;n2;n3;n4
Benj;2;2;3;2;1
```

I like to have a graph like this (input is the first csv):
[image]

I played around with some Gnu Plot files which i created before, but i always just got something totally different.

Maybe someone has a hint or something to help me?

Thank you very much,

Best regards
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Christoph, you need to transpose the data before plotting, the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash) should be helpful with that. To determine the number of rows in the data, recent versions of Gnuplot can use the `stats` command (see comment by Christoph below), otherwise the number of lines needs to be counted by other means.

Here is how you could handle both issues with external programs:

```
dfile = "data.csv"
nrec  = system("wc -l < " . dfile)
set datafile separator ';'
plot for [i=2:nrec] '<transpose --fsep \; -t '.dfile using i:xtic(1) with lines title columnhead
```

I used `wc` from coreutils to count the number of lines and `transpose` as suggested by [flyingsheep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778185/1331399) to handle the transposition.

Result:

[image]

Running the same script on data with more plots and data points:

*data2.csv*

```
name;n0;n1;n2;n3;n4
Benj;1;3;2;5;3
Silv;6;1;2;3;4
Steffi;3;2;2;4;2
Carl;2;4;5;3;2
```

[image]

Comment: Gnuplot has no builtin support to count the number of columns. The number of rows can be determined with the `stats` command: `stats 'data.csv' using 0; plot for [i=2:int(STATS_records)]...`.

Comment: @Christoph: I forgot about the `stats` command, I have added a comment about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong data file format for gnuplot. Usually, for a single plot, gnuplot uses all rows for a single column. With a data file like

```
name;Benj;Silv;Steffi
n0;1;6;3
n1;3;1;2
n2;2;2;2
```

the plot becomes as easy as

```
set datafile separator ";"
set style data lines
set key autotitle columnhead
plot 'data.csv' using 2:xtic(1), '' using 3, '' using 4
```

with the result (using 4.6.3):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already in the other answers, the most efficient way is certainly to **transpose the data** and use simple standard gnuplot plotting commands.

If you want a platform-independent ***gnuplot-only*** solution you could do the following:
If all rows have the same number of columns you can plot the data using the option `matrix` (check `help matrix`). There are a few examples here on SO. However, here, the additional difficulty is to get the xticlabels and the legend as well.

I tried a few script variations, but the one below was the only one I found which seems to work *unchanged* for both gnuplot4.6.0 (March, 2012) *and* gnuplot5.5.0 (July 2021).
I don't want to say the solution is beautiful, but it works with *gnuplot-only*.

**Data:** `SO22438313.dat` (taken from Thor's answer)

```
name;    n0; n1; n2; n3; n4
Benj;    1;  3;  2;  5;  3
Silv;    6;  1;  2;  3;  4
Steffi;  3;  2;  2;  4;  2
Carl;    2;  4;  5;  3;  2
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### plotting rows with xticlabels and legend
reset

FILE = "SO22438318.dat"

set datafile separator ';'
set yrange[0:]
set key noautotitle
# set colorsequence classic   # optional for gnuplot>=5.0

myTitles = ''

plot FILE matrix u (c=$1):3:(r=$2) every ::1:1 w l lw 2 lc var, \
        for [i=1:c]'' u (i):(i==1?myTitles=myTitles.' '.strcol(1):0,NaN): \
            xtic($0==0?xt=strcol(i+1):xt) w l lw 2, \
        for [i=1:r] '+' u 1:(NaN) every ::0::0 w l lc i lw 2 ti word(myTitles,i+1)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]