# awk split one column into multiple columns

Tags: bash, command-line, awk

How can split one column data into multiple columns based on column values using `awk`?
Example file and desired output is below. My `bash` version is 3.2.52(1).

```
$ cat examplefile
A
1
B
2
B
3
C
10
C
11
C
13
A
4
B
5
B
6
B
7
C
14
```

Desired output:

```
$ cat outputfile
A        B      C
1        2      10
null     B      C
null     3      11
null    null    C
null    null    13
A       B       C
4       5       14
null    B       null
null    6       null
null    B       null
null    7       null
```

Or forget about null values How can I obtain two columns as in the outputfile2?

```
cat examplefile2
A
1
B
2
B
3
cat outputfile2
A   B
1   2
    B
    3
```

Comment: What did you try? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: The purpose is putting A,B,C and their following row into different columns

Comment: What determines if a field is null ?

Comment: Consider the output as a matrix

Comment: number of columns=3 number of rows=n

Comment: Instead of commenting little things, try and edit your original question with a full good explanation, some examples and what you have tried. Otherwise, it is quite unlikely that people will spend the time to understand the problem and try to figure out a way to solve it.

Comment: I agree with fedorqui. Where the nulls come from?

Comment: Lets forget about null values

Comment: cat examplefile2
A
1
B
2
B
3
cat outputfile2
A   B
1   2
    B
    3

Comment: I am new to awk.Is there a way to split the data in two columns as in outputfile2?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{l=1;ll="";} {if (l) {ll=$0;l=0;} else {if (length(a[ll])>0) {a[ll]=a[ll]","ll","$0;} else {a[ll]=ll","$0;}l=1;}} END{for (k in a){print a[k];}}' examplefile
```

It works for any number of classes (A,B,C...).

The output is:

```
A,1,A,4
B,2,B,3,B,5,B,6,B,7
C,10,C,11,C,13,C,14
```

If you want it as columns, just have a quick look to the following post:
[An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts even though it is not exactly that I want.With your command and transpose code it gives the following output

Comment: A,1,A,4 B,2,B,3,B,5,B,6,B,7 C,10,C,11,C,13,C,14
What I want is the following

Comment: cat outputfile
A        B      C
1        2      10
         B      C
         3      11
                C
                13
A        B      C
4        5      14
         B       
         6       
         B       
         7

Comment: split by comma and use an inner for to transpose the input :-)