# Emacs: how to concatenate two rows together to form unique identifier?

Tags: string, vim, emacs, concatenation

I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857467/how-to-concatenate-identifier-specified-on-two-rows) about concatenating two rows to form unique identifier. I realized that this task may be very trivial in [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html): C-x C-t, concatenate, C-x C-t -- is it that simple? I am a Vim user and after pressing some buttons my emacs just ended to halt.

**How to do the concatenation in Emacs?**

---

I repost the INPUT and OUTPUT:

> **Input** where identifier specified by two rows 1-2
>
> ```
> L1_I                L1_I                C-14               <---|  unique idenfier 
> WWPTH               WWPT                WWPTH              <---|  on two rows
> 1                   2                   3
> ```
>
> **Goal:** how to concatenate the rows?
>
> ```
> L1_IWWPTH           L1_IWWPT            C-14WWPTH          <--- unique identifier
> 1                   2                   3
> ```

Comment: You seem to have an accepted solution in your original question. What is the purpose in asking for more solutions with different tools?

Comment: @phils this is clearly only about Emacs while the other question was about simplest *ix tool. I want to focus attention to Emacs here.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for superuser. No programming in sight...

Comment: @RickyA I think real programmers are able to choose the right tool at the right place: whether it is a Python, Vim, Emacs, Haskell, Mathematica or whatever -- now I am acknowledging that there is no sense to use a specific programming language for this kind of repetitive columnwise data processing rather a generic tool. Vim has a plugin to do this while builtin to Emacs, I really think it makes sense to switch to Emacs to do this. It looks to be the simplest tool for this task.