# Modifying specific row in CSV file using grep/awk//whatever

Tags: awk, grep

I have a .csv file with about 8k columns, 12 rows per column. The second row is in this format: ' name /id ' and I need it to only have the name part. What is the easiest way to remove everything after the / in the rows?

Comment: I would recommend you to transpose the table, then you can use awk to do your replacement very easily.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash

Comment: post some small, representative, sample input with the associated desired output, otherwise we're just guessing at your requirements.

Comment: each column is separated by a space??

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you might want to modify every 12th row in a file? You might try:

```
awk 'NR % 12 == 0 {print gensub("/.*$","",$0) ; next}
     {print}' INPUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do:

```
awk -F, '{sub(/\/.*/,"",$2)}1' OFS=, file
```

Example:

```
echo "test,paul/22,more" | awk -F, '{sub(/\/.*/,"",$2)}1' OFS=,
test,paul,more
```

Comment: When I try this, it only removed the /id part on the first line, after which the 5th row gets combined with the second column so that there is loss of information. Also, all other /id parts are still attached. This is a .csv file generated from Excel if that makes any difference...

Comment: @ahetman Post some of the file and how you like the output to be.