# Linux - Sort based on 2 fields names

Tags: linux, sorting

I have several txt files "file_i.txt" that look like this:

```
id, size, price, colour 
1, 2, 10, black
2, 8, 5, blue
...
```

All the files contain those fields, but the fields order may be different.

I would like to sort every file based on two features, price first and then size. I know it is possible to use the command sort to sort on two fields in this way:

```
sort -k2,3 -k1,2 file_i.txt
```

However, as the field position is different in every file, is there a way to sort based on the field name instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `sort` command should look like this:

```
sort -k3n -k2n input
```

where `N` in `-kN` is the number of the key, and `n` means sort numeric.

`sort` can't sort by field names. You need to get the column number somehow. I'm using `awk` for that:

```
kprice=$(awk -F', ' -vfield=price 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==field){print i;exit}}}' a.txt)
ksize=$(awk -F', ' -vfield=size 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==field){print i;exit}}}' a.txt)

sort -k"$kprice"n -k"$ksize"n a.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I just had to add head -1 file.txt ; tail -n +2 file.txt not to sort the headers

Comment: You may enjoy this discussion: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-01/msg00027.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write a script by yourself, say "mySort" and launch as:

```
./mySort "id" "size"
```

Pseudocode, assuming that the first line of file contains "column" name:

```
read input list
for each element in list, save the position (parsing first line)
apply sort
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do some preprocessing:

for each file:

- transpose file
- sort on first column (the names)
- revert the transposition

Then, all columns will be ordered the same way and you can use your standard `sort` approach.

---

Transposing a file in bash is already solved in other questions here on SO:

- [An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79642/transposing-rows-and-columns