# how to transpose fields with awk array?

Tags: arrays, awk

I am currently having trouble efficiently transposing fields within a `txt` file from columns to rows.

I have the following `input`:

```
1 2 3
A B C
D E F
```

and I would like the `output` to be:

```
1 A D
2 B E
3 C F
```

As of now I am isolating each field to a new file and transposing with:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";ORS="\t"}1' input | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {$1=$1;print}' > output
```

This is very inefficient and takes up disk space, so I was wondering if this could be accomplished with an `awk array`.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash