# Convert text files to single line

Tags: regex, linux, sed, newline

I tried to look for this but couldn't find anything that would suit me. 
My problem is that i need to convert content of multiple files that have the extension `.txt` to one line, for example:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I would like to convert to `1234` or `1 2 3 4`.

I also have subfolders that I would like to be included. I tried multiple attempts with Linux, and even tried TextCrawler 3 for Windows, but nothing really helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose a file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Try translate:

```
cat *.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

`-d` means to delete all newline `\n` characters.

If you want to have the space, you can do

```
cat *.txt | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove newlines or replace them with spaces:

```
$ paste -s -d '' infile
1234
$ paste -s -d ' ' infile
1 2 3 4
```

This only prints to stdout. To change the file in place:

```
$ paste -s -d ' ' infile > infile.tmp && mv infile.tmp infile
$ cat infile
1 2 3 4
```

To do this for many files, for example all `.txt` files in the current folder and all subfolders:

```
$ find -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'paste -s -d " " {} > {}.tmp && mv {}.tmp {}' \;
```

This is not very elegant as it creates a subshell in the `exec` part, but when there is redirection in the `exec` part of `find`, that's a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all line breaks from the files in *.txt

```
sed -z -i 's/\n//g' *.txt
```

Convert all line breaks to spaces in *.txt

```
sed -z -i 's/\n/ /g' *.txt
```

but for subdirectories you need some help from find.

```
find -name "*.txt" -exec sed -z -i 's/\n/ /g' {} ';'
```