# Rearrange row to column awk or shell

Tags: perl, shell, awk

Given a text file file.txt, transpose its content.

For example, if file.txt has the following content:

```
name age
alice 21
ryan 30
```

Output the following:

```
name alice ryan
age 21 30
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1729824/1030675

Comment: thanks it worked@choraba

Comment: trying to understand the code now..

Comment: I understood the first part of the code but not the str part.Can you please explain what does the code do?  I am a beginner in scripting.Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

With shell utils **cut** and **paste**:

```
for f in 1 2 ; do cut -d ' ' -f $f file.txt ; done | paste -d ' ' - - -
```

Outputs:

> name alice ryan
>   age 21 30

How it works.  The field separator in *file.txt* is a **space**, so both **cut** and **paste** (which have **tab** as a default field separator) must use the *-d ' '* option.  We know in advance there are two columns in *file.txt*, the **for** loop therefore requires two passes.  Pass #1, **cut** selects *column 1* from *file.txt*, pass #2, *column 2*.  When the **for** loop ends, what's fed to the pipe '|' looks like:

> name alice ryan age 21 30

Then **paste** outputs that three at a time (hence the three hyphens).

Comment: Thanks agc this also works but looks like cut and paste re-arranges words vs. awk parses and uses logic to do it? I am trying to learn as a new programmer, most efficient way to do it.Thnx.

Comment: @Neeld, see revised answer above with explanation.

Comment: Perfect . checking man pages of cut and paste .Thanks again.