# Make each 2 rows a separated column in UNIX

Tags: unix

**Hello i have this file.txt**

> a=a
>
> b=b
>
> c=c
>
> d=d
>
> e=e
>
> f=f

.
etc
(about 150 rows)

**I need the output to be:**

> a  b  c  d  e  f ....
>
> a  b  c  d  e  f ....

I already tried using `paste -d " " - - < file.txt`  but i need something to work with huge number of rows to columns.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose a file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/transpose-a-file-in-bash) with a slight modification in the input-field-separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
awk -F= '{
    arr1[NR]=$1
    arr2[NR]=$2
}
END{
    for (i in arr1) {
        printf("%s ", arr1[i])
    }
    print""
    for (i in arr2) {
        printf("%s ", arr2[i])
    }
    print ""
}' file
```

#### Output:

```
a b c d e f 
a b c d e f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the file using the internal field separator:

```
while IFS== read -r left right; do echo $left; done < "test.txt" | xargs
```

This gives you the left side. For the right side, you could do

```
while IFS== read -r left right; do echo $right; done < "test.txt" | xargs
```

If you are talking about only 150 rows, scanning the file twice should be finde.

Answer (score 1):

mash of `echo`, `cut` and `tr`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4

$ echo $(cut -d= -f1 ip.txt | tr '\n' ' ') ; echo $(cut -d= -f2 ip.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
a b c d
1 2 3 4
```