# Reorder Columns using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to reorder the columns using awk, sed... but I could not find the correct answer for that,
Basically, I want to reorder the Values from:

```
time 012016 022016 032016 04216

John 231 321 121 432

Mary 456 213 654 735

Charles 325 867 984 235
```

to:

```
time John Mary Charles

012016 231 456 325

022016 321 213 867

032016 121 654 984

042016 432 735 235
```

I tried to use something like but I am missing the numbers:

```
awk '{print $1}' ./database.dat | paste -d,  -s
```

output:

```
time John Mary Charles
```

Comment: Also see http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/transposing-rows-and-columns-3-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
time 012016 022016 032016 04216
John 231 321 121 432
Mary 456 213 654 735
Charles 325 867 984 235
```

Using `tr`, `wc` and `pr`

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < ip.txt | pr -$(wc -l < ip.txt)t
time          John          Mary          Charles
012016        231           456           325
022016        321           213           867
032016        121           654           984
04216         432           735           235
```

With `perl`, should be faster than `tr, wc, pr` mash

```
$ perl -lane '                                                                                                      
push(@a, @F);
END
{
    $r = $.; $c = $#F + 1;
    foreach $i (0..$#F)
    {
        print join "\t", @a[map {$i + $_*$c} 0..$r];
    }
}' ip.txt
time    John    Mary    Charles 
012016  231 456 325 
022016  321 213 867 
032016  121 654 984 
04216   432 735 235
```

- Input line is split on spaces, which gets saved in `@F` array. That array is concatenated for every line to `@a` array
- After entire file is processed, `$.` will have number of lines in input file. `$#F` gives index of last element of `@F` array
- Then print in required format

Comment: "should be faster than ..." ... well, except for the load time ;-> . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ghostdog74's awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980/3776858) three times to transpose your file:

```
#!/bin/bash

transpose () {
  awk '
  { 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
      a[NR,i] = $i
    }
  }
  NF>p { p = NF }
  END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
      str=a[1,j]
      for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
        str=str" "a[i,j];
      }
      print str
    }
  }'
}

transpose | transpose | transpose
```

Usage: `./this_script.sh < filename`

Output:

```
time John Mary Charles
012016 231 456 325
022016 321 213 867
032016 121 654 984
04216 432 735 235
```

I assume your file contains no empty lines.

---

Or modify ghostdog74's script to rotate in other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you're looking for :

**awk script**

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){val[NR][i]=$i}}
     NR==FNR{fc=NF}
     END{for(i=1;i<=fc;i++){
     for(rec=1;rec<=FNR;rec++){printf "%s%s",val[rec][i],(rec<FNR)?"\t":ORS}
     }}' filename
```

**Output**

```
time        John    Mary    Charles
012016      231     456     325
022016      321     213     867
032016      121     654     984
04216       432     735     235
```

<sup>**Assumption:** Every record in the file has the same number of fields</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The `rs` utility from BSD (obtained in Ubuntu using `apt-get install rs`).

```
$ rs -t 5
time 012016 022016 032016 04216

John 231 321 121 432

Mary 456 213 654 735

Charles 325 867 984 235
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
time     John     Mary     Charles
012016   231      456      325
022016   321      213      867
032016   121      654      984
04216    432      735      235
```

Transpose with TXR Lisp:

```
$ txr -e '(put-lines (mapcar (op cat-str @1 " ") (transpose (build (awk (f (add f)))))))' data
time John Mary Charles
012016 231 456 325
022016 321 213 867
032016 121 654 984
04216 432 735 235
```