# Linux script to transpose rows to columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk, transpose

I have below set of data and need somewhat transposed. I am struggling with script. Any help would be appreciated. All column/values are dynamic

File format:

```
ID    FieldName          FieldValue

1   Rooms Required?        Yes

1   Country of Meeting     US

2   Rooms Required? 

2   Country of Meeting  

3   Rooms Required? Yes

3   Country of Meeting  US

4   Rooms Required? No

4   Country of Meeting  BL
```

Output Required:

```
ID  Rooms Required? Country of Meeting

1     Yes                   US

2       

3     Yes                   US

4     No                     BL
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash

Comment: This isn't an actual duplicate, it's sorting the rows based on 2 different columns

Comment: What is the output and input field separator? Are the additional empty lines also input/output? Can fields have empty values?

Comment: You can take any pipe as input separator. Output also as Pipe. First column is ID , so cannot be empty. Second column will have column name so cannot be empty. Third column can be empty as its a value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea using `join` (and `bash` for the shell):

```
$ echo ID Rooms Country; \
  join -j1 -o '0 1.4 2.5' -a1 -a2 -e- <(grep -F Rooms data.txt) <(grep -F Country data.txt)

ID Rooms Country
1 Yes US
2 - -
3 Yes US
4 No BL
```

Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. However I need columns names well. Also can you explain what is Rooms data.txt and Country data.txt

Comment: `data.txt` is the file containing all the data, the same you published in your question. "Rooms" and "Country" are words in columns 2 in that file. As for the header, just add an `echo` line (I'll change my answer)

Comment: You are hardcoding the columns. I dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

A pure `awk` solution based on your fields separated by the tab character `'\t'` is as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" } { if ( $1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) next; A[$1][$2] = $3; H[$2] } END { printf "ID"; for (h in H) printf "\t" h; for (i in A) { printf "\n\n" i; for (j in A[i]) printf "\t" A[i][j] } print "\n" }' filename
```

And broken down:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "\t"  #Set Field Separator as the Tab
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"  #Set array order as numbers
}
{
    if ( $1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ )  #Skip all rows without numeric ID
        next
    A[$1][$2] = $3  #Store value in multi-dimensional array
    H[$2]           #Store header name
}
END {
    printf "ID"
    for (h in H)    #Print all headers found
        printf "\t" h
    for (i in A) {  #Print each record with corresponding values
        printf "\n\n" i
        for (j in A[i])
            printf "\t" A[i][j]
    }
    print "\n"
}' filename
```

Let me know if any further explanations are necessary. This will work with as many fields as you have set **and** in any order. If records don't have all the same fields, your output may look jagged.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, its not working as expected. I am getting data as below. Its not displaying value for Rooms Required?                                         ID      Rooms Required?    Country of Meeting

1       US

3       US

Comment: @Sunny, You'll have to expand on that, I'm not sure how different your results are. This is all hinged on the assumption that your fields are separated with a single tab `'\t'` character. I made this assumption because when I pasted your code in my IDE, the spacing lined up as if the spaces were originally tabs.