# Combing output of sprio and squeue using awk, paste, and piping

Tags: bash, paste, slurm

I would like to combine the outputs of sprio and squeue so that I can see JobId, Name, Priority, Age, State and Time in a one-liner without the use of files. I thought I could do this using awk, paste and some piping, but I don't know enough bash syntax to do anything other than getting the outputs to print consecutively.

```sh
{ sprio -u manninm; squeue -u $USER; } | paste
```

I would like to get certain columns of each output to print side by side, rather but I can only get the two outputs to print consecutively. If someone could point me to some resources or provide some suggestions, thanks.

```sh
JOBID PARTITION     USER   PRIORITY        AGE  FAIRSHARE    JOBSIZE  PARTITION                 TRES
         284926 standard   $USER     196140        117      95896        128     100000
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER  ACCOUNT ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
            284938  standard SM.fastq  manninm kretzler PD       0:00      1 (Priority)
```

Edit:
So after reading a little of the awk Tutorial, what I am actually wanting to print to the screen is fields 1-9 of the squeue command, and fields 1 and 4 of the sprio command.

```sh
{ squeue -u manninm; sprior -u $USER; } |
```

creates two records, and I would like fields 1:9 of record 1 and fields 1 and 4 of record two to print column wise to the screen. It doesn't seem to be as easy as I had hoped.

Comment: work your way thru the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to "matrix transpose" your output. Instead of `paste` above, try implementing the `awk` code in the top answer to this question, and piping your output into that instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `squeue` command can give you the priority. It accepts a `--output` parameter that you can use to choose the columns you want `squeue` to display through a printf-style format string. By default, it is

```
squeue --output "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R"
```

so if you add `%p` or `%Q` you will get an additional column in the output with the job priority.

```
squeue --output "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R %p"
```

or

```
squeue --output "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R %Q"
```

The difference between `%p` and `%Q` is that the former gives the priority as a floating point number while the latter gives it as an integer.

Note that `squeue` also accepts `--Format` (capital 'F') which takes a list of column names rather than a format string.

You will not get the details of the factors of the priority, though. If you want that, you will need indeed to merge the outputs of `squeue` and `sprio`. Be sure though to sort the outputs and to make sure only pending jobs are listed by `squeue` otherwise you cannot be sure that the correct lines are merge together with `awk`.

The best option in that case is to use the `merge` command that will reconcile outputs of both commandes based on the jobid:

```
join <(squeue -t PD | sort -n) <(sprio | sort -n) | column -t
```

Comment: Thank you for.  squeue -u $USER -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R %Q" gives the output I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "matrix transpose" idea linked in my comment above, but simplifying it down to "two rows at a time", which is what you seem to be shooting for, try this `awk` one-liner instead of paste:

```
bash { sprio -u manninm; squeue -u $USER; } | awk 'NR%2 {split($0,a)} !(NR%2) {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) print a[i],$i}'
```