# SHELL: Output contents of each FOLDER to each column of CSV

Tags: macos, shell, csv

I am trying to output contents of each folder into each column of CSV e.g.

`ls -R` is great but it Outputs everything into 1 column:

```
/Folder1:
1a.jpg
2a.jpg
3a.jpg
4a.jpg
5a.jpg

/Folder2:
1b.jpg
2b.jpg
3b.jpg
4b.jpg
5b.jpg

/Folder3:
1c.jpg
2c.jpg
3c.jpg
4c.jpg
5c.jpg

/Folder4:
1d.jpg
2d.jpg
3d.jpg
4d.jpg
5d.jpg

/Folder5:
1e.jpg
2e.jpg
3e.jpg
4e.jpg
5e.jpg
```

But I am trying to Output every folder into new column.

```
/Folder1:                      ,/Folder2:                      ,/Folder3:                      ,/Folder4:                      ,/Folder5:                      
1a.jpg                         ,1b.jpg                         ,1c.jpg                         ,1d.jpg                         ,1e.jpg                         
2a.jpg                         ,2b.jpg                         ,2c.jpg                         ,2d.jpg                         ,2e.jpg                         
3a.jpg                         ,3b.jpg                         ,3c.jpg                         ,3d.jpg                         ,3e.jpg                         
4a.jpg                         ,4b.jpg                         ,4c.jpg                         ,4d.jpg                         ,4e.jpg                         
5a.jpg                         ,5b.jpg                         ,5c.jpg                         ,5d.jpg                         ,5e.jpg
```

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'folder*' -printf '\f%f\n' -execdir ls {} \; | tr '\n' '\t' | tr '\f' '\n' | datamash --no-strict --filler '-' transpose` https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729824