# process text data and convert into cvc/excel format

Tags: python, bash, ksh

I got one requirement to process text file and collect two fields and convert those fields from column to row , finally convert  to spread sheet.  I tried to follow below URL
[An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash).
Unfortunately i was not able understand code properly.

Here is my text file

```
cat oralinux1_20191015.log
date collected          ||11-11-2019 03:58:54 GMT   ||
host name               || oralinux1                ||
kernel version          || 2.6.32-754.23.1.el6      || Good 
kernel architecture     || x86_64                   || Good 
hardware type           || virtual                  || Good
No.of CPU               || 4                        || Good
Installed Mem           || 16 Good                  || Good
/u01 file pct free      || 28 %                     || Good
```

my Requirement is

```
i need to pick 1st column and last column from the log and convert row as columns as csv/spread sheet 

Date collected,host_name,kernal version , kernel architecture , hardware type , No.of.cpu, installed_mem, 
                         Good,             good,                  good,          good,      good
```

So technically 1st filed of the file  will become 1st row and corresponding value in last column shoud be second row

Kindly help me on this issue. To be honest, I am not a extreme shell script developer and started my career recently.  Kindly help me on this.
I am ok  with shell script or python code, since i have started learning.

Thank you,

Durga

Comment: So, what did you try based on the info you found in the  link you added?

Comment: I suggest to add `awk` tag.

Comment: ```date collected   ||
host name    ||
kernel version   ||
kerneal architecture || 
hardware type   || 
No.of CPU     || Good
Installed Mem   || Good
/u01 file pct free  || Good

BEGIN { FS="||" OFS="," }
{ printf "%s%s", (FNR>1 ? OFS : ""), $ARGIND }
ENDFILE {
    print ""
    if (ARGIND < NF) {
        ARGV[ARGC] = FILENAME
        ARGC++
    }
}  ```    created temp file with required fields and used the above code.  Looks working  . But i need to insure that code is correct

Comment: Your sample output is not the cvs output you want. The two first rows have no value "Good", if you really want what you describe your second line should be `,,Good, Good etc`

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your inpout and your output becomes a lot easier.

```
while IFS='|' read -a line;   # the sed eliminates redundant space and pipes
do line1="$line1${line[0]},"; # accumulate & comma-delimit headers
   line2="$line2${line[2]},"; # accumulate & comma-delimit col3 values
done< <( sed -E 's, *\|+ *,\|,g' oralinux1_20191015.log ) # clean input
printf "%s\n" "$line1" "$line2" > relevant.csv # add newlines
```

Comment: Thank you, Let me open new request.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- OPs sample output has several typos (eg, capitalization, underscore in 2nd column name, extra spaces, etc)
- leading/trailing spaces to be removed from fields before writing to csv
- first 2 columns have empty values but should be written to csv as `,,`
- last line of the input file is to be ignored (ie, it doesn't show up in OPs sample output)

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F "|" '
BEGIN               { sep="" }                 # initial output field separator is empty string

/u01 file pct free/ { next }                   # ignore
                    {
                      gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$1)    # strip leading  whitespace from field 1
                      gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$1)    # strip training whitespace from field 1

                      gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$5)    # strip leading  whitespace from field 5
                      gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$5)    # strip training whitespace from field 5

                      labels=labels""sep""$1   # concatenate current field 1 onto variable
                      values=values""sep""$5   # concatenate current field 5 onto variable
                      sep=","                  # redefined separator as "," for rest of processing
                    }
END                 { printf "%s\n%s\n",       # generate output
                          labels, values
                    }
' oralinux1_20191015.log
```

Running the above against the OPs sample input file generates:

```
date collected,host name,kernel version,kernel architecture,hardware type,No.of CPU,Installed Mem
,,Good,Good,Good,Good,Good
```

Comment: Hello ALL,  Thank you so much for code help. Here problem is I have thousands of files  to process.  I need common heading   and process all the  files  and load in CSV  as one lines for each file.

Comment: sounds like you're changing your initial requirements; I suggest you either a) start a new question - making sure to provide (more) details or b) consider reworking/editing this question (above) - keeping in mind that the answers you've received so far will likely need to be deleted and/or heavily edited/rewritten