# In mac sed is not replacing newline to comma

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file

> cat test.txt

```
name: amit 
phone: 0000000000
```

I am trying to display like

```
name,phone
amit, 000000000
```

I try

```
cat test.txt | awk -F":" '{print $1}' | sed -n 's/,$//p'
and
cat test.txt | awk -F":" '{print $1}' | tr  '\n' ,
```

then save 1st string in `CSV` and then another by `>>`

when I use

```
cat test.txt | awk -F":" '{print $1}'
```

it shows

```
name
phone
```

my `sed` or `tr` is not wokring.. where I am doing wrong...

Comment: `sed` is not working because there is no comma in `name` or `phone`, your expectations are wrong. `-n` option with `p` would only print the result of substitution anyway.

Comment: btw, `-n` will hide the output of `sed`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
awk -F\: '
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, "", $i)
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str","a[i,j];
        }
        print str
    }
}' file
## => name,phone
##    amit,0000000000
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/dEGbQA).

This is based on  [An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash) with few changes:

- The field separator is set to a colon
- The leading and trailing whitespaces in a field are removed with the `gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/, "", $i)` line.