# Read values from .csv files and perform calculations using Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv, scripting

**Please help me on this question.**
How to perform this below operation (arithmetic calculations) using Shell Scripting.

*sample1.csv*

```
Assets,3,4,5
Loans,4,5,6
reported_activity,7,8,10
```

*sample2.csv*

```
credit,6,7,9
debit,13,5,8
affilate,9,4,5
```

take all first column values from *sample1.csv*

```
3
4
7
```

& take first column values from *sample2.csv* file

```
6
13
9
```

then calculate using formula :

```
Assets + ( loans + affiliate *-1) + reported_activity + (credit-debit)
                         

     3 +( 4*-1)+7 (6-13)
                              =3-4+7-7
                              = -1
```

similarly, need to perform arithmetic calculations for col2 & col3 of both the .csv files.

Comment: Your first column values look more like the second column...

Comment: Anyways, start with reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what Shawn said, I think your calculation is wrong.

Substituting the second column values in this part of the formula `(loans + affiliate *-1)` we have `(4 + 9 * -1)` which is `-5` (or, if you don't care about the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), it could be `-13`, but never `-4`

That said, this code does the trick:

```
cat sample*.csv > samples.csv

IFS=',' read -r -a Assets <<< "$(grep Assets samples.csv)"
IFS=',' read -r -a Loans <<< "$(grep Loans samples.csv)"
IFS=',' read -r -a reported_activity <<< "$(grep reported_activity samples.csv)"
IFS=',' read -r -a credit <<< "$(grep credit samples.csv)"
IFS=',' read -r -a debit <<< "$(grep debit samples.csv)"
IFS=',' read -r -a affilate <<< "$(grep affilate samples.csv)"

for ((i = 1 ; i < ${#Assets[@]} ; i++)); do
        echo -n "Column $i: "
        echo "$(( ${Assets[i]} + ${Loans[i]} - ${affilate[i]} + ${reported_activity[i]} + ${credit[i]} - ${debit[i]} ))"
done

rm -f samples.csv
```

```
$ bash samples.sh
Column 1: -2
Column 2: 15
Column 3: 17
```

Comment: the sample1 and sample2 csv files contain floating numbers in real scenario
While executing the above script, I am getting error  : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".387)

Comment: @blackhole bash doesn't do floating point math, just integer. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose the csv files and process them with awk. You can modify the formula in the print statement accordingly.

```sh
paste -d" " <(rs -c',' -C -T < sample1) <(rs -c',' -C -T < sample2) | awk 'NR>1 {print $1+$2-$6+$3+$4-$5}'
```

Alternate approach without using paste command

```sh
cat sample1 sample2 | rs -c, -C -T | awk 'NR>1 {print $1+$2-$6+$3+$4-$5}'
```

Paste command will join both the files and you'll have a final file with all the columns.

---

Since `rs` is available only in BSD systems, below snippet uses awk to transpose the input. Borrowing the transpose code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980/3319421)

```sh
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=NF;rowNr++) {
        cell[rowNr,NR] = $rowNr
    }
    maxRows = (NF > maxRows ? NF : maxRows)
    maxCols = NR
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=maxRows;rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1;colNr<=maxCols;colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", cell[rowNr,colNr], (colNr < maxCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

Save the above file as `transpose.awk` and run as below

```
awk -f transpose.awk sample1.csv sample2.csv | awk -F, 'NR>1 {print $1+$2-$6+$3+$4-$5}'
```

Comment: I guess I need to install rs  in my machine

Comment: Oops.. rs is a command found only in the BSD systems like MacOS it seems. Will update my answer.