# grep a word and print this line and column 1, column 3 of next three line

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a text like this,

```
test to print 
1     aa    ee    0.000     0.000     0.000
2     bb    ff    0.000     0.000     0.000
3     cc    gg        0         0         0
```

I want to print out like below,

```
               1   2  3
test to print  ee ff gg
```

or just

```
test to print  ee ff gg
```

how to do  that ?

Comment: try a websearch on something like `bash awk pivot file`

Comment: For inspiration you could have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980/3593896

Comment: There's not a single command to do what you want. You'll have to write some code.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, show the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: what string are you attempting to `grep` on? what happens if there are multiple lines with matches ... process all matches? process just the first match? and what happens if there's an overlap (eg, every other line has a `grep` match)?

Comment: if you are looking to `grep` on the string `test` ... would we also match on `retest` or `testing`? or do you want an exact (word) match?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mygrep(){
   grep -A3 "$@" | awk '
      NR%4==1 { c1r2=$0; next }
      NR%4==2 { c2r1=$1; c2r2=$3; next }
      NR%4==3 { c3r1=$1; c3r2=$3; next }
      NR%4==0 { c4r1=$1; c4r2=$3
                printf " \t%s\t%s\t%s\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",
                             c2r1, c3r1, c4r1,
                       c1r2, c2r2, c3r2, c4r2
              }
   ' | column -t -s $'\t'
}

$ mygrep test <<'EOD'
test to print 
1     aa    ee    0.000     0.000     0.000
2     bb    ff    0.000     0.000     0.000
3     cc    gg        0         0         0
EOD
                1   2   3
test to print   ee  ff  gg
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
test to print 
1     aa    ee    0.000     0.000     0.000
2     bb    ff    0.000     0.000     0.000
3     cc    gg        0         0         0
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\t"}{print /test/?$0:$3}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
test to print   ee  ff  gg
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK to use tab character as output record separator (`ORS`) that is when `print`ing tab is used as last character rather than newline. Then for each line I print depending on `test` presence in said line, if it is present whole line (`$0`) otherwise 3rd column (`$3`). If you want to know more about `ORS` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*