# Output all column numbers for a particular character

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

I have a matrix(about 10,000x10,000), and I want to find the column number that contains '0'.

Matrix (test.txt) :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 2 2 3 3 0 3 2 2 2
3 2 1 3 3 0 3 2 2 0
3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Output (example) :

```
2 4 6 10
```

I am new to LINUX SHELL, and have not found much in similar examples. Any help would be much appreciated!!

I just know how to find the row number using code: `grep -nw '0' test.txt|cut -f1 -d':'`, Maybe I can transpose the matrix first([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash))? And then use the code above, right? Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '
    /(^| )0( |$)/ {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i == 0 ) {
                cols[i]
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for ( i in cols ) {
            printf "%s%d", sep, i
            sep = OFS
        }
        print ""
    }
' file
2 4 6 10
```

The output above is not guaranteed to be in numeric (or any other) order due to the loop using the `in` operator, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array for details.

If you need the field numbers printed in increasing numeric order then change the script to the very slightly slower:

```
awk '
    /(^| )0( |$)/ {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i == 0 ) {
                cols[i]
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( i in cols ) {
                printf "%s%d", sep, i
                sep = OFS
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
' file
```

Comment: You can then sort the output of @EdMorton's awk command by piping it as follows: | tr " " "\n" | sort -n | tr "\n" " "

Comment: @BrandonETaylor `tr "\n" " "` would remove the final `\n` thereby turning the string into something that's no longer a valid POSIX text file and so YMMV  with what any subsequent text processing tool can do with it. If the output needs to be sorted that's easily handled inside the script. I added a version that orders the output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a matrix language for matrix operations, e.g. GNU Octave:

```bash
<infile octave --silent --eval "
[row, col] = find( dlmread(0) == 0 );
dlmwrite(1, unique(col))"
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
10
```

The 0 and 1 given to the dlm* commands refer to stdandard-in and standard-out, respectively.

If you want the output on one line, transpose and specify a delimiter, e.g. change `dlmwrite(...)` to `dlmwrite(1, unique(col)', ' ')"`

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I can transpose the matrix

Yes, just use tool which can do it, e.g. [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 2 2 3 3 0 3 2 2 2
3 2 1 3 3 0 3 2 2 0
3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

then

```
datamash --field-separator=' ' transpose < file.txt
```

gives output

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
3 2 2 3 3 0 3 2 2 2
3 2 1 3 3 0 3 2 2 0
3 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `datamash` that file is space-separated and instruct it to transpose. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that each line has exactly equal number of fields.

*(tested in GNU datamash 1.7)*

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be to pre-scan for existence of any `"0"` that isn't paired with other digits,

then simplify the columns to something resembling an `ASCII` bit-string, setting all non-zero columns to a `"1"` using high-speed `gsub()`, before splitting it with a new delim of `FS = "0"` :

```
1101011111 —> NF = 3
  ^ ^
```

> 

```
         11
    -[0]-1
    -[0]-11111
```

instead of having to loop `10,000 columns` every row, simply track the sum and difference of the string lengths for # of `1`'s, within each new column —- `e.g. (2,1,5) in this example` —- thus inferring the zeros located at `$3` and `$5`