# Fastest way to transpose large, space delimited text file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I face a large text file with which contains space delimited numbers, ranging from 0-9. Each line contains 3207 numbers and the file consists of 4611769 lines. I want to transpose this file.

Input example :

```
9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 29 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 29 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 0 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 1 1 2 9 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 9 2 2 2 2 9 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 9 2 2 2 2 2 9 2 2 1 9 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
...
```

I already tried this `awk`-solution : `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=a[i](NR!=1?FS:"")$i} END {for (i=1; i in a; i++) print a[i]}'` which I found [here](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/214843-transposing-huge-space-delimited-file-2.html).

I chose an `awk`-solution due to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash) where one user already benchmarked different solutions.

This operation runs now for more than 24 hours and I'm curious if there is by chance any other way in any possible language to achieve the same result in less computational time.

**Q: What is the fastest way to transpose such a file?**

EDIT I: The large amount of possible answers in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash) is an argument to not see this question as an duplicate. The simple `datamash` answer as suggested in the comments should help less experienced users with `bash` to find the answer to this question more easily.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 128GB RAM and a 550 GB swapfile.

Comment: The `awk` solution you use and the ones presented in [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824) are very different. Your solution is by far less efficient as you constantly rewrite memory. There are other solutions presented in the same question, example is `datamesh` which is for sure very efficient.

Comment: Also, that is a 28Gb file you are talking about. Are you sure you need to transpose it? If you need to operate on it, I would convert it into a binary format file which could be used as a lookup table and much faster than processing ascii tables

Comment: Alright. I will give `datamash`a try then!

Comment: @kvantour Sadly, I can't use something like a lookup table or some index switching. This new file is needed as an input for another algorithm and this only accepts this transposed format as a text file ):

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html#Reverse-and-Transpose

Comment: This helped to anwer my question but only after people here suggesting `datamash` instead of the most upvoted answer in the question, which I also mentioned in my question. I would like to write a one-liner for `datamash` and post this here as answer. I would argue that people, like me, get easily confused by the large amount of answers from the most upvoted answer, despite the probably best solution with `datamash` is not mentioned.

Comment: When you explore on StackOverflow, the most up-voted answer and accepted answer is not always the best answer. In this particular case, the awk answer is very generic for small things and does not need a lot of tinkering, but in your particular case, `datamash` or even the C-code listed down are the best solutions. The reason this has been duped is because this question would not give any additional value to the existing question. I strongly recommend to upvote the answer you found useful and even comment on it that this fitted your needs for a 28Gb file.

Comment: Furthermore, the `datamash` answer is listed down [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824) together with various other solutions.

Comment: Alright will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @kvantour and @Inian `datamash` seems to be the way to go. This one-liner should solve the question:

```
datamash transpose -t ' ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: It's absolutely OK to accept your own answer, as well (if you find it to be the best one, what is clearly the point here).  Need to [wait for 48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in order to do that.

Comment: You can optionally post performance results to your answer upon using each of the tool, e.g. datamash, awk or  perl