# Transform two columns to columnar data using ksh script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have a file with static format like below.

```
column|Data
```

Example:

```
Name|Joe
Surname|Robinson
Country|US
Gender|Male
```

I am expecting below output using a ksh script

```
Name|Surname|Country|Gender
Joe|Robinson|US|Male
```

Please suggest what approach I can use.

Comment: If you have `rs` available (or can get your sysadmin to install it), then that's the tool for this job.  Which then means it's not a programming problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: hanks for your help!! This did not work for me. however we figured out a workaround where we loading the data as is into the table and then writing SQL to pivot it

Answer (score 1):

You expect a `ksh` solution.
As `ksh` is `sh`-compatible a `sh` script is fitting too. Additionally it maximizes portability:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Expects the data file as first parameter.

for input in $(cat $1); do
    header="${header}|${input%|*}"
    data="${data}|${input#*|}"
done
echo ${header#*|}
echo ${data#*|}
```

If you prefer to use a pipe the suggestion of @Fravadona is the script for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Accepts the data from pipe

while IFS='|' read -r key value; do
    header="${header}|${key}"
    data="${data}|${value}"
done
echo ${header#*|}
echo ${data#*|}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! This did not work for me. however we figured out a workaround where we loading the data as is into the table and then writing SQL to pivot it